# How to Ignore Signal in C?

Tags: c, pthreads, signals, posix

I want to ignore signal for first 100 seconds of the thread life cycle, I developed this solution but its not working, what part Im missing?

**Problem statement:**
Write a program that has two threads - creating thread (thread A) and created thread (thread B). After creating thread B, thread A waits for thread B to terminate and then it terminates itself. Thread B terminates only under a special circumstance described later. Signal SIGINT (ctrl C) is blocked in thread B (i.e. only thread A handles SIGINT). Every time, the user presses ctrl C, thread A tries to cancel thread B. Thread B keeps pending any cancellation request received during the first 100 seconds of its life. Any cancellation request is honored once the first 100 seconds of the thread B's life are over. Also, thread B prints its current lifetime in terms of seconds after every 10 seconds.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define handle_error_en(en, msg) \
               do { errno = en; perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

void function_to_time(void);


static void *thread_func(void *arg)
{

    struct sigaction act;
    sigaction(SIGINT,NULL,&act);
    act.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    sigaction(SIGINT,&act,NULL); 

    sigset_t sigmask;
    sigemptyset(&sigmask);
    sigaddset(&sigmask, SIGALRM);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,&sigmask,NULL); 

    sigemptyset(&sigmask);
    sigaddset(&sigmask,SIGALRM);
    sigaddset(&sigmask,SIGINT);

    alarm(100);

    int sigintsReceived = 0;
    int sigalrmsReceived = 0;

    while( 1 == 1)
    {
        int recvdSig;
        sigwait(&sigmask,&recvdSig);

        if( recvdSig == SIGALRM ) 
        {
            if( sigalrmsReceived == 0 )
            {
                sigalrmsReceived++;
                printf("\npthread_cancel is enabled\n");

                sigset_t sigmask2;
                sigemptyset(&sigmask2);
                sigaddset(&sigmask2, SIGINT);
                sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,&sigmask2,NULL); 

                sigaction(SIGINT,NULL,&act);
                act.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
                sigaction(SIGINT,&act,NULL); 
            }

        }
    };

    return 0;
}


int main(void)
{

   sigset_t set;

   pthread_t thr;
   void *res;
   int s;

   s = pthread_create(&thr, NULL, &thread_func, (void *)&set);
   if (s != 0)
       handle_error_en(s, "pthread_create");

   sigemptyset(&set);
   sigaddset(&set, SIGINT);
   pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);   

    int recvdSig;
    sigwait(&set,&recvdSig);

    if( recvdSig == SIGINT ) 
    {
        printf("Signal received\n");
        printf("main(): sending cancellation request\n");
        s = pthread_cancel(thr);

        if (s != 0)
            handle_error_en(s, "pthread_cancel");
    }

    s = pthread_join(thr, &res);
    if (s != 0)
    handle_error_en(s, "pthread_join");

    if (res == PTHREAD_CANCELED)
    printf("main(): thread was canceled\n");
    else
    printf("main(): thread wasn't canceled (shouldn't happen!)\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

Comment: What part is not working?

Comment: its not ignoring the signal

Comment: @June What do you mean by not ignoring? The default behavior for SIGINT is to terminate your program, if that isn't happening, your signal mask worked.
You should, however, take into account that signals break blocking commands, waking up the process (they interrupt a read or a sleep or a wait) and that can't be avoided.
Look at your return values, is it EINTR (-4)?

Comment: Also, signals and signal handlers are for your entire process, not per thread.
Any of the threads could handle the signal, but it's usually handled by the main thread

Comment: @immortal and what about `pthread_sigmask(3)`?

Answer (score 1):

Read carefully [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) & [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). You can only use (both directly and indirectly) *async-signal-safe* functions inside signal handlers. Be aware of `EINTR` in [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) and test that after every blocking system call (e.g. after [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) or *stdio* functions).

Signals and [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) don't work well together. A signal handling is for an entire process (not for individual threads in it).

You could use [sigprocmask(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html) and better yet [pthread_sigprocmask(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html).

A common trick is to setup a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) to self at initialization and [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) one or a few bytes in the signal handler and [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) then [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) that elsewhere. This trick is [explained](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html) in Qt documentation.

Use the debugger `gdb`  and [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to debug your program.

Answer (score 0):

> Write a program that has two threads - creating thread (thread A) and
>   created thread (thread B). After creating thread B, thread A waits for
>   thread B to terminate and then it terminates itself. Thread B
>   terminates only under a special circumstance described later. Signal
>   SIGINT (ctrl C) is blocked in thread B (i.e. only thread A handles
>   SIGINT). Every time, the user presses ctrl C, thread A tries to cancel
>   thread B. Thread B keeps pending any cancellation request received
>   during the first 100 seconds of its life. Any cancellation request is
>   honored once the first 100 seconds of the thread B's life are over.
>   Also, thread B prints its current lifetime in terms of seconds after
>   every 10 seconds.

If I understand well, you can try:

- Thread B can mask SIGUSR1 and SIGINT (`pthread_sigmask`), setup an alarm of 10 seconds (`alarm`) and its handler that would print the current time, count the number of those interrupts, and when 10 is reached unmask SIGUSR1.
- Thread A can mask SIGUSR1 and SIGALRM and catch SIGINT, when SIGINT is received it will deliver a SIGUSR1 all of this while joining thread B.

In this scenario SIGUSR1 is used as "cancellation" for thread B.